# Using d3-request from node

Tags: node.js, d3.js, d3-request

I'm coding d3.js library to be used from the browser, using [d3-request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request) to get some json files.

I amb testing the parts from node.js using tape, so the different parts can be tested before bundling all the library.

When I use

```
request.json(url, callback)
```

The calldoesn0t return the content. Looking [the tests at the d3-request library](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/test/json-test.js), I see that this require is used:

```
require("./XMLHttpRequest");
```

So the library can be used with nodejs, but I can't reproduce it in my library. Also, the docs say that d3-request can be used directly with node (even [this tweet by Mike Bostock](https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/700113000103960576) says so), but I can't find any example.

Does somebody has an example for this?

To make it clearer, when executing:

```
request.json("sample.json", function(error, json) {
if (error) throw error;
console.info(error, json);
});
```

The output is *undefined undefined*

Comment: `The call doesn't return the content`; what does that mean?  Does it throw an error?

Comment: It means that the callback function has no parameters passed. if I change callback to function(error, data), both error and data are undefined. No error is thrown. I'll edit the question to show it.